ContextClosedEvent occurs when Run 'Tests in 'java''
package com.nhnacademy.aiot.ruleengine.listener;

import com.nhnacademy.aiot.ruleengine.send.MessageSender;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextClosedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ServerClosedMessageSender implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {
    private final MessageSender messageSender;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(@NotNull ContextClosedEvent event) {
        messageSender.send("RuleEngine", "Rule Engine server shutdown!!");
    }
}

enter image description here
enter image description here
I'm trying to make the server send message when it is close. It works well, but this event also occurs when I run all of my tests. This is not what I expected. How can I fix this problem?

Ofcourse it runs during your test as your context will get closed as it should. That is not a problem that is expected behavior.
